# How to edit /etc/printcap?

Tags: rhel, cups

We recently changed domain and host name on a RHEL8 server from `old.domain.name` to `more.better.name`.

I happened to notice a reference in `/etc/printcap` to `old.domain.name`.

```
[user@box ~]# cat /etc/printcap 
# This file was automatically generated by cupsd(8) from the
# /etc/cups/printers.conf file.  All changes to this file
# will be lost.
office_printer_123|office_printer_123:rm=old.domain.name:rp=office_printer_123:
[user@box ~]#
```

Correct hostname shows

```
[user@box ~]# hostname
more.better.name
[user@box ~]#
```

The server has been restarted a few times since changing the hostname.

I found zero other references to `old.domain.name` with

```
[user@box ~]# grep -r "old.domain.name" /etc/
[user@box ~]#
```

`old.domain.name` is not found in /etc/cups/printer.conf

```
[user@box]# cat /etc/cups/printers.conf
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v2.2.6
# Written by cupsd on 2021-08-24 10:01
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<Printer office_printer_123>
UUID urn:uuid:e74ed8e4-e5e6-30b9-64b9-2283cc9c93e7
AuthInfoRequired none
Info office_printer_123
MakeModel HP LaserJet 600 M601 M602 M603 Postscript (recommended)
DeviceURI ipp://111.222.111.222
State Idle
StateTime 1629813648
ConfigTime 1618257051
Type 8425668
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>
[user@box]#
```

How do I change what's in the `printcap` file? And where could it be pulling `old.domain.name`?

Comment: `man 8 lpadmin` ?

Comment: Did you actually read the man page? Zero references to either `printcap` or `rm` or `remote machine`

Comment: Use the cups web interface to make a trivial modification to office_printer_123. Or name a big change and then revert it. The act of changing the configuration should automatically update printcap. If this works (as documented) I'll write it as an answer with a couple of references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the modification timestamp of the `/etc/printcap` file. If it is older than the current uptime of the server, then it may have been written by an older version of CUPS, and the current version may simply not have updated it on start-up for some reason.

You could also try moving the printcap file away and restarting CUPS. At least on Debian 11, the current CUPS seems to create the file if it does not exist but does not update it if it exists but is stale.

Apparently because of this, `/etc/printcap` is now a symlink to `/run/cups/printcap` in Debian 11, and since `/run` is a tmpfs filesystem, it obviously won't survive a reboot.

```
systemctl stop cups
mv /etc/printcap /etc/printcap.old
systemctl start cups
diff -u /etc/printcap.old /etc/printcap
```

Answer (score -2):

`/etc/printcap` is auto-genereated by `cupsd` - and it is there for BSD printing compatibility, so you do not edit the file directly when using CUPS.

```
# mv /etc/printcap{,.bk}
# systemctl restart cups
# ls -l /etc/printcap{,.bk}
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 261 Aug 31 09:51 /etc/printcap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 261 Jul 18 08:02 /etc/printcap.bk
```

Comment: The OP obviously did know that. The question is: How can CUPS remember the old domain name?

Comment: Was this file older than `/etc/cups/printers.conf`? Was the file with odd content present after the server was restarted a few times since changing the hostname? No info provided. We can only guess and CUPS is not free of bugs, so...